# Why am I unable to pass UIImageView as argument?

Tags: ios, uiimageview, swift2

Im trying to create a class that adds blur effect to images passed into it when initialized but am getting an error to pass in the image view. I'm using Xcode 7.3, Swift 2.2; here is my code, please take a look.

This is my class

```
class addBlurEffect: UIViewController {

private var newBlurEffect = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light))
private var objectToBlur = UIImageView()

convenience init(objToBlur: AnyObject) {
    self.init()

    objectToBlur = objToBlur as! UIImageView
    blur()
}

func blur() {
    newBlurEffect.frame = objectToBlur.bounds
    objectToBlur.addSubview(newBlurEffect)
}
```

}

This is my code in the ViewController.swift file

```
@IBOutlet weak var blurHeader: UIImageView!

var addBlur = addBlurEffect(_: blurHeader)
```

But I get this error "Instance member 'blurHeader' cannot be used on type 'ViewController'"
[instance error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IpP5G.png)

Any help is greatly appreciated in pointing me to a possible solution. Thanks.

Oh, I also tried the following with the same results:

```
convenience init(objToBlur: UIImageView) {
    self.init()

    objectToBlur = objToBlur
    blur()
}
```

Comment: How about `var addBlur = addBlurEffect(objToBlur: blurHeader)`?  (Seems to work in a playground.)

Comment: Also why on earth would you want to use `AnyObject`? Why throw away the type safety?

Comment: And use a capital letter at the beginning of a class name, or I personally will come to your house and smash your computer.

Comment: Hey originaluser2, I actually tried it both ways. AnyObject was actually my second attempt in case that was the reason it didn't work. When I first wrote the code, this is what I used "var addBlur = addBlurEffect(objToBlur: blurHeader)" and on the other side it was "convenience init(objToBlur: UIImageView)"

None of that worked and it still does not work. Thanks for the input guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems with this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var blurHeader: UIImageView!
var addBlur = addBlurEffect(_: blurHeader)
```

First, the second line is not even Swift. It's just nonsense. Perhaps you mean:

```
@IBOutlet weak var blurHeader: UIImageView!
var addBlur = addBlurEffect(objToBlur:blurHeader)
```

But you won't be able to say that either, at least not the way you've shown it, because you cannot initialize a property (`addBlur`) with reference to another property (`blurHeader`).

Comment: Hey Matt,
Please note that I originally had my code as var addBlur = addBlurEffect(objToBlur:blurHeader), in fact it was Xcode that suggested that I used _: instead. Also, it's possible to call a parameter without specifically stating the name and use the underscore instead. I will try you suggesting and remove the property from the initialization and see what happens. Thanks

Comment: @MarlonMingo Your code won't compile as it stands. I'm explaining why. I don't know what you think calling `addBlurEffect(_: blurHeader)` would mean, but I assure you that it is not Swift.

Comment: I see... thanks.
I was able to fix the issue using your suggestion. I removed the init() and used the blur function with a parameter instead
func blur(objToBlur: UIImageView) {} and in the ViewController.swift I used

    var addBlur = addBlurEffect()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
        addBlur.blur(blurHeader)
    }

Comment: Perfect. This fixes your syntax, plus you don't refer to `blurHeader` until you are inside `viewDidLoad`, which is perfectly legal. And this is still early in the life of the view controller, so all _other_ code will find your `addBlur` completely configured already.